# Table doesn't appear to be accepting new rows?

Tags: mysql, row

It has come to my attention that one of my websites is not allowing users to register. Upon looking through the table and running through different scenarios it appears as if my table isn't allowing any more rows.

I'm on PHP 7.0 running MariaDB on cPanel. My table was at 499 rows and I could not add a new user from the script I haven't changed in years. I tested the code on a new table and it inserted the value just fine and the rest of the script executes just fine. This is leading me to believe it's something with the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ipaddress` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `salt` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `country` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(33) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(400) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastactive` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `photo` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `about` text NOT NULL,
  `intrests` text NOT NULL,
  `aim` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `yahoo` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `msn` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `website` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `points` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `view` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `joined` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `act` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `xlink` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `isstaff` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `stgr` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `rights` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `stpr` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `trs` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `sttitle` varchar(60) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for table `members`
--
ALTER TABLE `members`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `id` (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `members`
--
ALTER TABLE `members`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=502;
COMMIT;
```

```
///Here is the insert code for my PHP script
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO members (name,ipaddress,salt,gender,country,password,email,act)  VALUES (
'".mysqli_real_escape_string( $connection, $member['name'])."',
'".mysqli_real_escape_string( $connection, $ip)."',
'".mysqli_real_escape_string( $connection, $enurl)."',
'".mysqli_real_escape_string( $connection, $member['gender'])."',
'".mysqli_real_escape_string( $connection, $member['country'])."',
'".mysqli_real_escape_string( $connection, $pass2)."',
'".mysqli_real_escape_string( $connection, $member['email'])."',
'".mysqli_real_escape_string( $connection, $anumber)."')");
```

My error_log does not populate with any errors nor is there an error dumped on the page. Like I said the script runs it's course just fine inserting these same details into other tables.

Comment: To anyone who comes here with a similar issue.... Check Mysql Strict Mode

Comment: Note that your KEY definition is redundant

Comment: And look at properly preparing and binding your queries